# What's the execution flow of below PHP scripts?

Tags: php

I have a test.php:

```
<?php

include "MyString.php";

print ",";
print strlen("Hello world!");
```

and a MyString.php:

```
<?php

namespace MyFramework\String;

function strlen($str)
{
    return \strlen($str)*2; // return double the string length
}
print strlen("Hello world!");
```

The output of test.php is 24,12 but how was the output produced? What are the execution flow of test.php?

Also there is a back slash in:

```
namespace MyFramework\String;

function strlen($str)
{
    return \strlen($str)*2; // return double the string length
}
```

Is this '\' means using namespace?

Comment: I don't know why somebody gave this question a minus, but this is a question about PHP namespace, a new feature after PHP 5.3. If you think this question is boring or of no use, please let me know your point

Comment: I didn't downvote but, FYI, PHP5.3 is old news and is obsolete.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

execution of `test.php` includes `MyString.php` and executes main level code in `MyString.php`

`MyString.php` prints the result of the strlen ***in its own namespace*** (ie calling `MyFramework\String\strlen()` rather than the standard PHP `strlen()` function from the global namespace) which outputs `24` (12*2).... then `MyString.php` terminates and control is returned to `test.php`

`test.php` next prints a comma, and then prints the result of `strlen()` which uses the standard PHP strlen because it's no longer executing in the `MyFramework\String` namespace, so the output is 12

The `\` before `strlen` inside the namespaced `strlen()` function in `MyString.php` means use the standard (root namespace level) strlen() function